# Obtener cantidad de miembros de cada grupo

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un problema con mi consulta SQL, en el cual intento contar los miembros (`group_memberships`) de cada grupo (`groups`), pero en todos los grupos me muestra la cantidad de miembros en 1. ¿Alguna forma de cómo hacerlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Básicamente, quiero que cuente cuántos miembros hay en cada grupo dependiendo de la tabla `group_memberships` (`group_id` es la id del grupo en la tabla `groups` y `player_id` es la id del usuario que está unido a dicho grupo)

```
// SQL
$group = Db::query('SELECT * FROM groups WHERE id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6)->fetch_assoc();

$group_members = Db::query('SELECT * FROM group_memberships WHERE group_id = ' . $group['id'])->fetch_assoc();

// HTML
<?=count($group_members);?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres contar cuantos usuarios hay en cada grupo simplemente usa

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CONTEO FROM group_memberships GROUP BY group_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que deseas es contar la cantidad de `group_id` deberás entonces usar la función de agrupación `COUNT()` quedando tu consulta de este modo:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(group_id) AS Total
FROM group_memberships
JOIN groups ON groups.id = group_memberships.group_id
GROUP BY id;
```

Solo te muestra uno por:

Aunque estas agrupando por id, lo único que estas consiguiendo es que dicha agrupación solo tome el primer renglón de cada `id` que encuentra y entonces al tomar solo esa fila solo te va a mostrar 1

Comment: Lo que quiero es que cuente cuantos miembros hay en cada grupo utilizando la tabla `group_memberships`. `group_id` es la id del grupo en la tabla `groups` y `player_id` es la id del usuario que está unido al grupo.

Answer (score 0):

ya probaste haciendo el count con la consulta?.

me refiero algo como esto.

```
$group_members = Db::query('SELECT count(group_id) FROM group_memberships WHERE group_id = ' . $group['id'] group by group_id)->fetch_assoc();
```

espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: No amigo, ¿alguna otra solución?